# Defining all undefined functions

Tags: binary-analysis, ghidra

I analyzed a binary, and lots of functions weren't detected as such - the bytes weren't detected as assembly. I read about the Aggressive Instruction Finder analysis and used it. Now the instructions are detected, but the functions (at least some) aren't.

For a single function, I know that I can press F to define it. Is there any way to do that automatically for all/most undefined functions?

Example for an undefined function:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

In ida you can make use of a idapython function called `MakeFunction`. You can basically iterate through the code and define undefined functions.

ExampleScipts: [IDA MakeFunction](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/102513/idc.MakeFunction)

However If you ask this question specifically for Ghidra then I believe there's a plugin to run idapython scipts in Ghidra.

[Run IDAPython scripts in Ghidra](https://github.com/daenerys-sre/source)

Hope this helps.